# Liquibase doesn't create or replace view using sqlFile

Tags: sql, view, liquibase

I have many sql files for creating or replacing views and I want to reuse them through `sqlFile` in liquibase changelog instead of using `createView` xml tag.

I use:

```
<sqlFile path="VI_NAME.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```

Instead:

```
<createView viewName="VI_NAME" replaceIfExists="true">
    SELECT
    ...
</createView>
```

But views not created with this approach!
I debug the way using createView and sql generated by liquibae is the same as in sql file (only schema is added to view name - but this doesn't solve my problem)

PS: 
Logging for `sqlFile`:
*SQL in file VI_NAME.sql executed*

Liquibase Version: 3.1.1

Comment: You can try to use also a sql file which does not exist to see what message will be displayed in the liquibase log file.

Comment: Hm.. seems like liquibase does't write that file not exists.. I have mistake in my paths(

Comment: I was wondering if that was the problem. That bug is fixed in the upcoming 3.2.0 release

Answer (score 0):

Use `runOnChange` attribute.

```
<changeSet author="liquibase" id="my_view" runOnChange="true"><sqlFile path="VI_NAME.sql"/>
</changeSet>
```